# How get comma separated values from Xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file looking like this (I have lots of data on this xml , but this is the relevant row )

```
<add Key="CpaData" Value="62502634,10:64917154,15:205481314,20:205485754,25"/>
```

I need to get values from CpaData key value , in way that ones I have some element (array , list) where I have elements that separated by ":" like this  62502634,10 , and after it I need access to one of this sell (62502634 or 10  )
my code looking like this

```
private int GetTargetCpaData(string campaignId)
{
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"reportConfig1.xml");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    int i = 0;
    var elements = doc.Descendants("Configuration");
    string cpaValues = "";
    var cpaDataValues = doc.Descendants().Attributes().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Value == "CpaData").ToString();
    string[] temp = cpaDataValues.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string items in temp)
    {
        string[] temp2 = items.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (temp2[i] == campaignId)
        {
            cpaValues = temp2[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return Int32.Parse(cpaValues);
}
```

but for some reason "cpaDataValues" return :"add Key="CpaData" and not the value string .
what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: By the way, I recommend you use [`XmlConvert.ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Int32.Parse()` because the XML function is locale-invariant, which is almost always the correct way to parse XML files.

Answer (score 3):

You need to filter on one attribute, then return a different one, like so:

```
    var cpaDataValues = doc.Descendants()                   // Search all elements of the document
        .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "add")              // Look for element with local name "add"
        .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("Key") == "CpaData")// With an attribute named "Key" with value "CpaData"
        .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("Value"))          // Select the value of the "Value" attribute.
        .FirstOrDefault();                                  // And return the first found.
```

I searched on element local name rather than name since there may be a default namespace not shown in your question.